# PHP split different informations

Tags: php

i'm looking for a solution for this problem:

i've an array like this

```
Array (
    [0] => 
    [1] => ─╡Bügeleisen╞─ # TF -flofloflo- ~DORSAI~ 
    [2] => ASH 25 # TF silentglider (u) WS 
    [3] => Gutinedu ottomatic 
    [4] => Deep Space Three # TF Kleissi1978 (gu) F & P 
    [5] => crafted by trapper12 # TF trapper12 VR 
    [6] => -8- Mrs-Shooter (u) -=SC=- 
    [7] => ? Pitch Pink ? # TF CreShoK -=V=- 
    [8] => Standard Libelle silentglider (u) WS 
    [9] => crafted by phiLLLdd phiLLLdd (u) -=SC=- 1 
    [10] => V8 Vote111 (u) 3R 1 
    [11] => Nimbus silentglider (u) WS 1 
    [12] => Speed Astir silentglider (u) WS 1 
    [13] => Metal Gear Ray # TF KlappstuhI > ReX < 1 
    [14] => RK-Weporinag # TF ImperatorMar (u) -=SC=- 1 
    [15] => RK-Smecid # TF CrazyNeo82 (gu) NKD 1 
    [16] => der Mittelpunkt # TF TruNaDe A K
)
```

I need the values of every dataset, e.g.:

```
|      1      |  2  |    3      |   4   |
─╡Bügeleisen╞─ # TF -flofloflo- ~DORSAI~
```

I thought, i can solve it with a simple explode but take a look at the 2nd

```
|   1  |  2 |     3     | 4 | 5|
ASH 25 # TF silentglider (u) WS
```

So ... there can be spaces in the names and the dataset can contain 4 or 5 values.

I need an Array looks like this:

```
arr[1]['val1'] = '─╡Bügeleisen╞─' 
arr[1]['val2'] = '# TF'
arr[1]['val3'] = '-flofloflo' 
arr[1]['val4'] = '~DORSAI~' ...
arr[2]['val1'] = 'ASH 25' 
arr[2]['val2'] = '# TF'
... ... ...
```

Comment: Can only `# TF` contain space?

Comment: are you splitting on # and - and ~

Comment: Without certain delimiters, it's going to be very challenging to do automatically...

Comment: @Shao Khan see what you can do to get the incoming data in a better format (eg, tab separated may be a good idea).

Comment: What about lines 8-12, they don't have `#`. Where do the fields end on those lines? You need to specify how to parse the data more generally.

Comment: which data are you trying to get from 1st line?, 2nd,3td..?

Comment: **Glavić**: all items can contain spaces - 
**Dagon**: uhm ... LOL - 
**VictorKilo**: Yes, therefore i ask the experts here ;) - 
**Mike Graf**: The data comes with copy'n paste, no chance to put tabs or else- 
**Barmar**: The '1' on line 9-15 ignore pls. - 
**alpera**: look my example above.

Comment: look here http://pastebin.com/9Dsuztfr there is the array i've now. Problem: 
**1st array:** pos 1 is the item name, pos 2 is a mark, 5 is a name and 7 is a extra name
**2nd array:** pos 1 and pos 2 are the name, 3 is a mark, 6 is a name, 9 is a extra name with additional information. 

hope it helps a bit.

Comment: problem solved .... i'v seen there is a JSON string too, so i use this ;) much easier